# Visual Studio pre build event not writing to output window until finished

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am calling a python script from the pre build event like this:
`py -3 "$(SolutionDir)/build.py"`

Now the problem is, the output of the script isn't written to the output window in visual studio until the script is finished. The script can take a few minutes the first time it is run, so I'd like to see what it is working on.

Is there a way to keep the output window up to date with the output of the script?

Comment: This is normal output redirection lossage, py.exe does not flush its stdout buffer until the buffer fills up or the program terminates.  Consider the `-u` option.

Comment: Adding `-u` so it becomes `py -3 -u "$(SolutionDir)/build.py"` doesn't change a thing. This is also only a problem with Visual Studio. When running the command through a console the output is printed as expected, so I don't see how py.exe is at fault here.